# What is the second homotopy group of $\mathbb{R}^3 - \mathrm{line} - \mathrm{point}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose one removes a line and a point from $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the line not intersecting the point). What is the second homotopy group of the resulting space?

**My thoughts:** the fact that a point is missing gives rise to the usual set of maps that wrap the two-sphere around the point an integer number of times. So there must be a $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup. However, one can also stretch the sphere around the missing line before wrapping it over the point, and this seems to give rise to an inequivalent mapping from the two-sphere to the space.

Indeed, one can stretch the sphere around the line any integer number of times before wrapping it around the point, and since $\pi_2$ is always Abelian, my guess is that

$$\pi_2 = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \,.$$

However, I don't know how to check whether this is correct, nor do I know of any general techniques to attack this sort of problem. Any help in these regards is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good start but the answer is a bit more complicated than that.

1. Show that your space deformation retracts on the wedge sum of a circle (that goes once around your line) and a $2$-sphere (that goes once around your point).
2. Show that the universal cover of that wedge sum is an infinite chain of ...sphere-line segment-sphere-line segment... where the fibre is therefore $\Bbb Z$.
3. From the homotopy exact sequence you see that $\pi_2(X)$ is the free abelian group on infinitely (countably) many generators.

Comment: How does homotopy exact sequence work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To echo HK Lee, could you please clarify point 3? The other two points are very clear.

Comment: @HKLee it's explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups).

Comment: @gj255 see the above link. In the present case, $F=\Bbb Z$ has trivial homotopy groups in positive degree so $\pi_2$ is the same for the base and the total space.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier : Thank you.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The one thing I haven't quite grasped is the computation of the homotopy group of the universal cover. I understand that this is the same as the homotopy group of the base space.

Comment: @gj255 The easiest way to see it is that a wedge of spheres is the $2$-skeleton of a product of the same amount of spheres.